# Do DECLARE assignments consume time at runtime?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2017. I have a bunch of DECLAREs with assignments, e.g.

```
DECLARE @_File_Status_None INT = 0
DECLARE @_File_Status_New  INT = 1
DECLARE @_File_Status_Open INT = 2
```

At run time, does this take any actual time to run?

Basically, is this complied into a series of assignment statements, or is it compiled into pre-filled locations in memory (so that this construct takes no time at all at runtime)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory for the variables is allocated as part of the cached plan. Some info on that [in my answer here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bfe5c756-f339-4192-9687-2d6969491797/sql-server-variable-declarations-and-the-query-optimizer?forum=transactsql).

The assignment to the variables happens at runtime so will take some negligible amount of time.

You can see this from

```
if 1=0
begin
DECLARE @_File_Status_None INT = 0
DECLARE @_File_Status_New  INT = 1
DECLARE @_File_Status_Open INT = 2
end

SELECT @_File_Status_None /*Doesn't have the value `0`*/
```

I've never cared about this execution time. It will likely be measured in microseconds and there are always much bigger fish to fry when it comes to query optimisation.

Comment: Thanks. The example proves it. I may have up to a hundred of these Declares, as this is how I do constants, and I'm about to write a tool that will automatically keep the constant declarations aligned amongst the source code of the stored procs.

Comment: @Evan - one potential problem with this method of defining constants is that the variable values are not assigned to until run time so at compilation time they are unknown. This means cardinality estimates may not be as accurate as when using a literal constant (unless also combined with `option (recompile)`

Comment: Thanks. This database has hundreds of constants being used in 270+ stored procs. I'm willing to trade-off some performance for ease of programming (and ease of handing over to another developer). Also, this helps prevent the literals from being wrong.

Comment: @Evan -  Now SQL Server 2019 has inline scalar UDFs one potential approach would be to create an inline UDF for each constant and reference that. This means the values can be shared between modules and also at compilation time the literal values can be known by the optimiser for potentially better plans